# Pro Tools Removing Sound After Bouncing To Quicktime Movie

Tags: pro-tools, track, building-a-soundtrack

After having created a project with Pro Tools which includes a movie that I have added audio tracks to, after I bounce the project to a Quicktime movie via this option in the file drop-down menu, I try playing the project in Pro Tools again but the audio from all tracks is completely silenced although the movie will run as normal in its separate window. Does anyone know why the tracks aren't playing?

Comment: Great question for the DUC over at Avid.com They will get you answer much faster if you give more detail on your routing and import/export procedure. Good luck

Comment: Thanks as it happened after leaving the computer overnight and coming back today - the software was working fine - just opened the project as normal and both the sound and video were playing as normal.....strange

Comment: Ok can you than please close or remove your question?

Comment: Why - is there no-one else who uses Pro Tools 9 that's ever had this problem?